# Suppressing section in Crystal Reports when column has no value equal to "something"

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following problem:
 -- I have one database table with the following structure : < Age, Gender , Wage., ..>
 -- I have one Crystal Reports report with two subsreports , each displaying a graph of wage per age , one for records that have male gender the other for female gender.
 I would like to suppress one subreport if the table has no records with gender value "male" or "female".
Thanks,
Vali

Answer (score 0):

Create **SQL Expressions** which count occurences of male and female values in the gender column. For example:

```
(select count(male) from dbtable where gender = 'male')
```

Then suppress the subreport you want simply by a suppress formula `{%SQL_expression} = 0`

A good presenatation about SQL Expressions is here: https://www.box.com/shared/i2jk8yohku

Alternatively you can use a formula which reads the fields while reading them from database using **WhileReadingRecords** and a shared BooleanVar.

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Shared BooleanVar isMale;
isMale := False;
if (dbTable.Gender = 'male') then
  isMale := True;
isMale;
```

Then use the shared BooleanVar to suppres the sbreport.